# Inline table valued function is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Function is as :

```
create or alter function Supplier_Name(@sup_id int)
returns table
as
    return select SupplierName 
           from suppliers 
           where SupplierID = @sup_id
```

SQL to run :

```
SELECT 
    ProductID, ProductName, 
    dbo.Supplier_Name(dbo.products.SupplierID) AS "Supplier Name"    
FROM products
```

Comment: Don't use functions for things like this anyway. You'll end up with poor performing code that falls over once your tables are large. Just join to the table where you need it

Comment: it is my requirement to create a function like that. Please provide corrections to make this work @MartinSmith

Comment: Change it to a Scalar-Valued Function.

Comment: Could you please describe how to change it @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Comment: If your requirement is to use a table-valued function you need to `cross apply` it in the code that consumes it.

Answer (score 2):

To use the results of a table-valued function you need to `cross apply` it in the code that consumes it, e.g.:

```sql
create table dbo.Suppliers (
  SupplierID int,
  SupplierName nvarchar(50)
);
insert dbo.Suppliers (SupplierID, SupplierName)
values
  (1, N'Acme Rockets'),
  (2, N'Acme Sprockets');

create table dbo.Products (
  ProductID int,
  ProductName nvarchar(50),
  SupplierID int
);
insert dbo.Products (ProductID, ProductName, SupplierID)
values
  (1, N'Nova Force', 1),
  (2, N'Turninator', 2);
go

create or alter function dbo.Supplier_Name(@sup_id int)
returns table
as
return
  select SupplierName
  from dbo.Suppliers
  where SupplierID = @sup_id;
go

select ProductID, ProductName, SN.SupplierName as [Supplier Name]
from dbo.Products
cross apply dbo.Supplier_Name(Products.SupplierID) SN
```

| ProductID | ProductName | Supplier Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nova Force | Acme Rockets |
| 2 | Turninator | Acme Sprockets |

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to inline it as a subquery like you can do with any other table.

Also, you should use square brackets not quotes for your alias.

```
SELECT 
    p.ProductID, p.ProductName, 
    (select SupplierName from dbo.Supplier_Name(p.SupplierID)) as [Supplier Name]    
FROM products p
```

Note this assumes it will always return a single row which I assume it would if `supplierId` is a unique key; if it did return multiple rows you would aggregate eg with `max()` or `top()`.